# Ignore firebase.firestore.timestamp

Tags: firebase, vue.js, timestamp, nativescript, nativescript-firebase

My project used `@Nativescript/firebase`(https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) ignores methods of `firebase.firestore.timestamp`, and returns `undefined` by properties.

The below is minimum reproduction

app.js

```
import Vue from "nativescript-vue";
import Home from "./components/Home";

var firebase = require("@nativescript/firebase").firebase;

firebase
  .init({})
  .then(
    function () {
      console.log("firebase.init done");
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
    }
  );

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h("frame", [h(Home)]),
}).$start();
```

Home.vue

```
import { firebase } from "@nativescript/firebase";

export default {
  computed: {
    async message() {
      const Ref = firebase.firestore
        .collection("comments")
        .doc("07bhQeWDf3u1j0B4vNwG");
      const doc = await Ref.get();
      const hoge = doc.data();
      console.log("hoge.commented_at", hoge.commented_at); // CONSOLE LOG: hoge.commented_at Sat Oct 23 2021 22:44:48 GMT+0900 (JST)
      console.log("hoge.commented_at.seconds", hoge.commented_at.seconds); // CONSOLE LOG: hoge.commented_at.seconds undefined
      const hogeToDate = hoge.toDate();
      console.log("hogeToDate", hogeToDate); // no console.log appear
      return hogeToDate; // simulator shows "object Promise"
    },
  },
};
```

I also tried `const hogeTimestampNow = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now();` then no console.log appear...

Environment

- vue.js
- Node.js v14.17.6
- nativescript v8.1.2
- nativescript-vue v2.9.0
- @nativescript/firebase v11.1.3

Answer (score 1):

If you dive into the source of [`@nativescript/firebase`](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase), in particular looking at [`/src/firebase-common.ts`](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/src/firebase-common.ts), you can see that `firebase` is a custom implementation and not the object/namespace normally exported by the ordinary Firebase Web SDK.

It uses a custom implementation so that it can be transformed depending on the platform the code is running on as shown in [`/src/firebase.android.ts`](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/src/firebase.android.ts) and [`/src/firebase.ios.ts`](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/src/firebase.ios.ts).

Of particular importance, is that Firestore's Timestamp objects are [internally converted](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/2fe6fe6156f2665b2017c711d92a38f593c3bbee/src/firebase.android.ts#L429-L430) to JavaScript Date objects when exposed to your code as each platform has its own version of a `Timestamp` object. Because the exposed JavaScript Date object doesn't have a `seconds` property, you get `undefined` when attempting to access `hoge.commented_at.seconds`.

The [equivalent of `Timestamp#seconds`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/dbd54f7c9ef0b5d78d491e26d816084a478bdf04/packages/firestore/src/lite-api/timestamp.ts#L70-L74) would be `Math.floor(hoge.commented_at / 1000)` (you could also be more explicit with `Math.floor(hoge.commented_at.getTime() / 1000)` if you don't like relying on JavaScript's type coercion).

```js
function getSeconds(dt: Date) {
  return Math.floor(dt.getTime() / 1000)
}
```

While you can import the `Timestamp` object from the Modular Web SDK (v9+), when passed into the NativeScript plugin, it would be turned into an ordinary object (i.e. `{ seconds: number, nanoseconds: number }` rather than a `Timestamp`).

```js
import { Timestamp } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';

const commentedAtTS = Timestamp.fromDate(hoge.commented_at);

docRef.set({ commentedAt: commentedAtTS.toDate() }) // must turn back to Date object before writing!
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!
I understand how to convert to seconds in my project.

Answer (score 0):

`firebase.firestore.timestamp` does not work via `@nativescript/firebase` as @samthecodingman said.(https://stackoverflow.com/a/69853638/15966408)

Just use ordinally javascript methods and edit.

I tried

- get timestamp from firestore then convert to milliseconds
- get date with `new Date()` then convert to milliseconds

and same miliseconds logged.

via firestore

```
const Ref = firebase.firestore.collection("comments").doc("07bhQeWDf3u1j0B4vNwG");
const doc = await Ref.get();
const hoge = doc.data();
console.log("hoge.commented_at in milliseconds: ", Math.floor(hoge.commented_at / 1000)); 
// CONSOLE LOG: hoge.commented_at in milliseconds:  1634996688
```

via javascript methods

```
const getNewDate = new Date("October 23, 2021, 22:44:48 GMT+0900"); 
// same as hoge.commented_at
console.log("getNewDate in milliseconds: ", getNewDate.getTime() / 1000); 
// CONSOLE LOG: getNewDate in milliseconds:  1634996688
```